# RestKit RKObjectMapping issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following JSON returned from my restkit call:

```
{"test":{"123423":{"id":"123423","type":"mood","stress":null}}}
```

and I am using the following mapping

```
RKObjectMapping *testResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TestDataResponse class]];

[testResponseMapping addAttributeMappingToKeyOfRepresentationFromAttribute:@"itemNumber"];
[testResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                             @"(itemNumber).id":@"id",
                                                             @"(itemNumber).type":@"type",
                                                             @"(itemNumber).stress":@"stress"
                                                             }];

RKResponseDescriptor *testResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:testResponseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"test" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

This is not quite right as I'm not sure I am handling the first "123423" (which is a number that changes) correctly.
How do I update my code to accommodate this properly? Thanks!

Comment: It appears you are doing everything correctly, what kind of error  are you getting?

Comment: I am getting "Expected status code in (200), got 500"

Comment: RKObjectManager getObjectsAtPath is the method failing

Comment: Error 500 is an internal server error. That would indicate something being wrong on your server.